# plotting in html in r

Tags: html, r, plot

Let me clarify a bit.
I have a list of students and their marks during a period of time for different subjects. I just want to start with something very easy, like listing their names on a web page:
Peter W
Andreas Q
Lisa W
Renate S
and by clicking on 'Peter W' I should get several plots containing the marks vs time for different given topic (maths, sciences, ...). Actually the best would be to get first a menu associated to the name where I can select 'maths' and then I get the plot corresponding to the performance of Peter W in maths.

I would like to write a list of people in html such that if I click on one name, I get a number of plots associated to that name.
Any idea where I could find examples or info about how to do something like that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update you're question and add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was shiny for R.
Useful links:shiny.rstudio.com